# Non-Zero Exit Status Code, yet application exits normally

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, aix, exit-code

**Problem**

I have this wierd situation with a Java EE batch process, it uses spring. But to summarize, I run the batch from unix usnig a command like this:

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -DJNDI_HOME=${JNDI_HOME} com....batch.CommandLineBatchProcessor 8
```

the batch does its job correctly, and exits normally. I know it exists normally because it makes till the last statement of the main method.

This might be wrong, but I am not sure how can I debug this issue? How can I identifiy where did the non-zero exit code occur? If I explicitly add System.exit(some number) at the very end of the main method It exists on "some number".

the exit code i am getting is 132? I am just puzzled as to why I a getting a positive exit code when the code executes no problem? and exits normally?

any hints on how to debug it, or similar stories that happened with you would be greatly appreciated. I am not expecting a fix.

**Summary**

Is there such a thing as a non-exiting non-zero exit code

**what I have done:**

- add a shutdown hook and it executes it ok, but dont know how to find out what is the state of the application from there
- Comment out the main logic of the process -> it exits on 0, but the logic is executed all they till end if uncommented, but gives 132 error message

**external issues**

I have this error message that says "Illegal instruction(coredump)" from AIX whenever i run java from there.. but it's never been a problem before..could that be related?

Comment: Have you ever searched for 132 (or its hex representation) in the code?

Comment: Exit status 132 corresponds to "illegal instruction," so the message is definitely related. You could try opening the core dump in a debugger to find out what happened.

Comment: I still cannot figure it out. because core dump on AIX is not valid and cannot be used. I think the issue has to do with JRE/AIX incompatibility because it does not happen in our production environment which has an older AIX version and an older JRE build.